# Couldn't find [model] without an ID with has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models - Mom, Dad and Kid. The Mom and Dad only belong to each other through the Kid, so the associations are like this:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :dad
end

class Mom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  has_many :dads, through: :kids
end

class Dad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  has_many :moms, through: :kids
end
```

I'm trying to route to a Dads' moms by searching for any mom and not just the one's through the kids of the Dad:

```
http://localhost:3000/dads/superdad/moms

resources :dads do
  resources :kids
  resources :moms
end
```

In my Moms controller I tried to find the ID of "superdad":

```
def index
   @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
   if params[:q].present?
     @moms = Mom.search(params[:q], page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
   else
     @moms = Mom.none
   end
end
```

But run into this error:

```
Couldn't find Dad without an ID  
# line 8 @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
```

Is it possible to use @dad in this way when the Mom has no direct id towards it? What do you suggest I do? I need to get to @dad.name (and more) on the Mom's index page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
def index
   @dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
   if params[:q].present?
     @moms = Mom.search(params[:q], page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
   else
     @moms = Mom.none
   end
end
```

use `params[:dad_id]` instead of `params[:id]`. The reason is that the route generated for index action of `MomsController` would be:

```
dad_moms GET    /dads/:dad_id/moms(.:format)          moms#index
```

`params[:dad_id]` would give you `dad_id` as `superdad` from `http://localhost:3000/dads/superdad/moms`. In your case, you are looking for params[:id] which does not exist. Hence, the error.